# Single Page Template and Multipage Templates in jquery mobile and their processing speeds?

Tags: jquery-mobile, processing

I am having concerns with html5 based mobile Apps.

In jquery mobile I have seen some of the multipage templates which are working good on chrome as a webpage but if i consider mobile Apps single page templates works good but so many lines of code in one html file is very much hard to understood.

Is there any tool that can bind multiple HTML files in a single file which helps in fast processing?

also which are the best practices that i can follow as to handle these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I'm trying to make sense of your question and I think you should probably go with something like http://www.codiqa.com/

There you can use a GUI to build jQuery Mobile apps.
They have a 15 day free trial (formerly 30), so you can check it out before you decide.

Comment: as at today 4/12, 15-day trial.. (for future reference)